# GRANT EXECUTE ON SomeProc TO SomeRole AS dbo

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

I have a role `ExecSP` which I use to manage who can execute stored procedures. `EXECUTE` permission is granted on all SPs to this role.

I also use SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) to manage MS SQL Server database schema.
In the file where my SP is defined, I have this:

```
CREATE PROC SomeProc AS
.
.
.

GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON SomeProc TO ExecSP
```

However, when I apply the change to the target database, and do the schema comparison, it reports differences in SP permissions, where on the DB side I have this:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SomeProc TO ExecSP AS dbo
```

I've [tried to understand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql) what `AS dbo` part represents, but I couldn't.

My questions:

1. Does it mean that the SP will be executed with `dbo` rights, regardless of who is executing it? (I guess/hope it doesn't.)
2. Why is this added automatically?
3. I want this SP to be executed with the rights the caller has - how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use the AS principal clause to indicate that the principal recorded as
>   the grantor of the permission should be a principal other than the
>   person executing the statement. For example, presume that user Mary is
>   principal_id 12 and user Raul is principal 15. Mary executes GRANT
>   SELECT ON OBJECT::X TO Steven WITH GRANT OPTION AS Raul; Now the
>   sys.database_permissions table will indicate that the
>   grantor_prinicpal_id was 15 (Raul) even though the statement was
>   actually executed by user 13 (Mary).

That is wrong. Try to reproduce it and you'll get the error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot find the object 'X',
>   because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Even if Mary and Raul are members of sysadmin fixed server role.
And that is why: the AS clause is not intended to be used with WITH GRANT OPTION, but, as BOL 2008R2 offline version says:

> AS principal  Specifies a principal from which the principal executing
>   this query derives its right to grant the permission

That is, the mentioned above repro with Mary and Raul both sysadmins fails because Raul has no explicit permission on object X, and even if it has no need to be granted an explicit permission being sysadmin, this time we get an error because the permission check is not bypassed: server checks the sys.database_permissions to find the appropriate permission.

The AS clause is used in following scenario: we have a database role MyRole that is granted some permission WITH GRANT OPTION. Let's Mary be a user-member of MyRole. Now Mary wants to give the permission she has to Steven, but the simple

> GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::X TO Steven

failed because as a simple user Mary has no permission on X, but if she writes

> GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::X TO Steven as MyRole

it works fine: there is the explicit grant to MyRole is sys.database_permissions

Returning to your question, if you try now to script any of your object using Management Studio (database -> tasks -> generate scripts, select some objects and in "advanced" turn on "script object level permissions"), you'll get the same script: GRANT ... AS DBO. 
And only in the case with the role you'll see GRANT .. AS MYROLE.
So the Studio always scripts out the grantor from sys.database_permissions, but it's not an "audit", you'll never see other principals that are not dbo except for the role case, and even if you has a principal that has only CONTROL permission on only one object, when he grants someone a permission to that object, in sys.database_permissions the grantor will be dbo.

Comment: By the way, you say >I have a role ExecSP which I use to manage who can execute stored procedures. EXECUTE permission is granted ***on all SPs*** to this role<. If your role needs EXECUTE on ALL procedures, why do you give the permissions on EVERY procedure? Why don't you give just EXECUTE to this role, without specifying all procedures one by one? This way the role has a permissions on all procedures in this db, already existing and future procedures as well

Comment: Actually, you're right. `GRANT EXECUTE TO [ExecSP]` is all I need.

Answer (score 2):

1. From BOL:

> Use the AS principal clause to indicate that the principal recorded as
>   the grantor of the permission should be a principal other than the
>   person executing the statement. For example, presume that user Mary is
>   principal_id 12 and user Raul is principal 15. Mary executes GRANT
>   SELECT ON OBJECT::X TO Steven WITH GRANT OPTION AS Raul; Now the
>   sys.database_permissions table will indicate that the
>   grantor_prinicpal_id was 15 (Raul) even though the statement was
>   actually executed by user 13 (Mary).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql

So in this case the engine is recording the grantor as dbo, rather than the account running the actual code.

2. I'm unsure why this would be - perhaps due to some aspect of the schema compare, dbo is used to ensure there are no orphaned records in terms of the grantor? Perhaps someone else can shed some light.
3. It should do this anyway - do you mean in this case the caller is the ExecSP role or the user themselves? Either way this should already be happening, if you've assigned the role or not.

Comment: 1. So, if I understood it correctly, it is only an _audit record_ where it's written who granted this permission?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Check out the sys.database_permissions table to check it out on your servers.

Comment: 3. My intention is to make sure that, whatever is happening inside of the SP, it happens with the permissions of a user executing SP.

Comment: Yeah so that should happen anyway - as always though, test, test and test some more. I've not come across anything that would make me think this situation wouldn't work. If your ExecSP role just allows execution of the procedure, all other permissions should come from the user / any other roles you've created etc.